# React update dynamic list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a dynamic form with fields. I've got the value from the fields in a list and am trying to update it reactivly.

Why is this not working:

```
const { data, setData, errors, put, processing } = useForm({
    ...props.questions.map((q, index) => q.pivot.answer)
});

{
    question.field_type == 'TEXT_INPUT' && (
        <TextInput 
            value={data[index]}
            className="w-full"
            onChange={e => {
                let d = data;
                d[index]+=e.target.value;
                console.log(d);
                setData(d);
            }} />
    )
}
```

TextInput looks like this:

```
export default ({ label, name, className, errors = [], ...props }) => {
    return (
        <div className={className}>
            {label && (
                <label className="flex text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-2" htmlFor={name}>
                    { label }
                </label>
            )}

            <input
                id={name}
                name={name}
                {...props}
            />

            {errors && <div className="text-sm mt-2 text-red-500">{errors}</div>}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Any Idea how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

```
const {data, setData, errors, put, processing} = useForm({...props.questions.map((q, index) => q.pivot.answer)});

{question.field_type === 'TEXT_INPUT' && (
    <TextInput
        value={data[index]}
        className="w-full"
        onChange={e => {
            const d = [...data];
            d[index] += e.target.value;
            console.log(d);
            setData(d);
        }}/>
)}
```

Try to completely replace local state.
Also, is index defined?

You can try this:

```
{ props.questions.map(question, index) => (
<>
    {question.field_type === 'TEXT_INPUT' && (
        <TextInput
            value={data[index]}
            className="w-full"
            onChange={e => {
                const d = [...data];
                d[index] += e.target.value;
                console.log(d);
                setData(d);
            }}/>
    )}

</>
) }
```

Comment: Hey that does not work `Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.`

Comment: Can `data` be empty?

Comment: It's not clear if you are looping/mapping from data with an `index` variable.
In your example `index` obviously isn't defined.